# PyQGIS Zonal Stats

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I have several raster layers (37) which I want to extract the maximum value of it's band to the vector associated. I used to run it as batch process and works fine.
The problem is that I also have a bunch of vector files, one for each day of the month. So I'm doing the same process (batch process represented by the figure below) 30 times.
[image]

I know this could be solved with a loop, but how?
I presume that first I have to do the zonal stats on Python Console, with a loop for the raster layers and print the results to the vector layer associated (day 1 - *_2023055*). Then, a loop for the day before (day 2 - *_2023056*), something like n+1...

I'm beginning my Python studies.